# List coalgebra translating code from Haskell to SML

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, category-theory, unfold

I'm trying to translate this piece of code in Haskell that describes List anamorphism but can't quite get it to work.

The final three lines are supposed to generate a function count which given an int will produce an int list [n, n-1, ..., 1]

Haskell code:

```hs
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

type List_coalg u x = u -> Either () (x, u)

list ana :: List_coalg u x -> u -> [x]
list_ana a = ana where
  ana u = case a u of 
    Left _ -> []
    Right (x, l) -> x : ana l

count = list_ana destruct_count
destruct_count 0 = Left ()
destruct_count n = Right (n, n-1)
```

What I have so far:

```ml
type ('a, 'b) List_coalg = 'a -> (unit, 'a*'b) Either

fun list_ana (f : ('a, 'b) List_coalg) : 'a -> 'b list = 
  let
    fun ana a : 'b list = 
      case f a of
        Left () => []
      | Right (x, l) => x :: ana l
  in
    ana
  end

fun destruct_count 0 = Left ()
  | destruct_count n = Right (n, n-1)

val count = list_ana destruct_count
```

I get the following error:

```
catamorphism.sml:22.7-24.35 Error: case object and rules do not agree [UBOUND match]
  rule domain: (unit,'b * 'a) Either
  object: (unit,'a * 'b) Either
  in expression:
    (case (f a)
      of Left () => nil
       | Right (x,l) => x :: ana l)
```

Not sure how to fix this as I am not super proficient in SML.

Comment: I fixed the error by simply changing the line ```type ('a, 'b) List_coalg = 'a -> (unit, 'a*'b) Either``` to ```type ('a, 'b) List_coalg = 'a -> (unit, 'b*'a) Either``` but I'm not sure why it works? I'm trying to understand this from a paper but I am not generally sure how this type line works

Comment: I mean, the Haskell version has `type List_coalg u x = u -> Either () (x, u)` - clearly the type parameters in the tuple are in the opposite order as the type parameters declared by the type. So you need to do the same thing in your ML if you want the types to line up the same way.

Comment: @amalloy what is the point of reversing the order of parameters? I don't quite get it

Comment: In this case, I don't think there a point in reversing the arguments. Typically that's done when you want to partially apply a type constructor, e.g. to define a functor instance, but here that's not needed. (Even though, technically, a coalgebra is u->F u for some functor F. But we don't need to know that here.)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, the type parameters got mixed up. With a bit of renaming for comparison:

```hs
type List_coalg a b = a -> Either () (b, a)            --  (b, a)
```

```ml
type ('a, 'b) List_coalg = 'a -> (unit, 'a*'b) Either  (*  ('a * 'b)  *)
```

which leads to a mismatch after pattern-matching on the pair:

```hs
    Right (x, l) -> x : ana l
    -- x :: b
    -- l :: a
```

```ml
    Right (x, l) => x :: ana l
    (* x : 'a *)
    (* l : 'b *)
```